# How to hide the cmd windows when running external executables that are called through an OCRA Ruby executable?

Tags: ruby, ocra, fxruby

I have a ruby script that runs many external executables (.exe). I run these executables in two different ways.

1. `sytem(program)`
2. `IO.popen(program)`, in this case I need the PID since later on I monitor this process.

My UI is designed with FX ruby. When I run the program through my cmd console (`ruby MyScript.rb`) everything works fine and I don't see any pop-up.

Then, I generate an exe with the OCRA gem by using the following syntax:
`ocra MyScript.rb --gem-all --windows`

The exe is generated correctly; however, when I run any external program, through system or popen, there is a cmd window popping up during the time the exe is running.

Is there a way to hide these cmd windows?

Comment: Can you post an example of how you run these executables? E.g. `system 'some argument here'`

Comment: Hi @engineersmnky,
Sure, when using "system" I do something like this:

'cmdTitle = "7Zip"
pathProgParm = "c:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7zFM.exe"
cmdFn = "start " + "\""+ cmdTitle + "\" " + pathProgParm
system(#{cmdFn})'

When using a pipe I do something like this:

'pathProgParm = "c:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe -h"
pipe = IO.popen(pathProgParm)'

Once I've generated the exe through OCRA, I see a DOS box displayed while the other executables are running. Once the process is completed the DOS box is automatically closed.